# TDD and UML together

Tags: tdd, uml

I'm new to TDD approach so I'm wondering if anyone experienced wit this could enlighten me a little. I would like to get some leads how to use UML and TDD methodology together.

I've been used to: Design with UML --> Generate skeleton classes (and then keep it synchronized) -> Implement and finally Test. I must admit that testing part was the worst one, so I started to look for something else - TDD. So I have some general knowledge what is it about but before I proceed further, I am interested knowing how it goes together with software design especially UML.

So when I first design/create test, how can UML fit in? Would it be possible to design classes first, from them create skeleton classes, from them generate Unit tests which would be "filled" before actual implementation of UML pregenerated classes, would this approach break whole TDD? Or is there any other way that would keep UML and TDD together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So when I first design/create test,
>   how can UML fit in? Would it be
>   possible to design classes first, from
>   them create skeleton classes, from
>   them generate Unit tests which would
>   be "filled" before actual
>   implementation of UML pregenerated
>   classes, would this approach break
>   whole TDD? Or is there any other way
>   that would keep UML and TDD together?

If you create an entire skeleton class - by which I assume you mean a class with all methods defined but empty - before writing your first test, then I would say you are not doing TDD, and lose the benefits of TDD.  As we do TDD - Test-Driven *Design* - our tests incrementally lead us to the next elements - methods and classes - that our program needs.  If you have predetermined, pre-specified in UML, what your classes and methods are, a great deal of your design is already done, and either your subsequent development is constrained to follow it, or you have wasted effort that subsequent work will undo.

There may be ways to use both UML and TDD together for design, but as you have described it, you are doing the design within UML, before TDD ever gets a chance.  That won't give you the full benefit of TDD.

Answer (score 16):

The TDD cycle is test, code, refactor, (repeat) and then ship.  As the TDD name implies, the development process is ***driven*** by testing, specifically that means ***[writing tests first](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/software-testing/0321146530/test-driven-development-patterns/90?bookview=search&query=%22test+first%22)*** before developing or writing code.

---

*The first paragraph is purely definitional ... from how [Kent Beck defines TDD](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/software-testing/0321146530/test-driven-development-patterns/90?bookview=search&query=%22test+first%22) ... or how [Wikipedians generally understand TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)  ... I thought it was necessary to belabor the point with this definition, because I am not certain whether everyone is really discussing the same TDD or if others really understand the implications the [most-important part or the] definiton of TDD, the implications of **writing tests first**.  In other words, I think more of the focus of the answers to this question should delve a bit deeper into TDD, rather than explaining a bias for/against UML.  The lengthy part of my answer relates to my opinion on using UML to support TDD ... UML is just a modelling language, certainly not required to do TDD; it could get in the way if applied inappropriately ... but UML can help with understanding requirements to write tests, how modeling can help refactor if needed and how collecting the artifacts of the process speeds the documentation of shipped code.  I would welcome any comments, criticisms or suggestions, but please don't vote my answer up or down because you agree or don't agree with the first paragraph ... the TDD acronym is Test-Driven Development which means Test-First Development.*

---

Writing a test first implies that the developer understands the specifications and requirements FIRST ... obviously, any test is written should fail until the code gets written, but in TDD, the *test* must be written *first* -- you can't do TDD without being focused on understanding a requirements specification before you write tests, before you write code.  There are situations where the requirements do not exist at all; requirements elicitation involves a bit of hacking a pre-pre-alpha version to "throw mud at the wall to see what sticks" ... that sort of thing should not be confused with development, certainly not test-driven development, it's basically just one form of requirements-elicitation for a poorly-understood application domain.

UML diagrams are one form of requirements input to TDD.  Not the only one, but probably better than written specifications if people who are knowledgeable in creating UML diagrams are available.  It is often better work with visual diagrams for better communication in exploring the problem domain [with users/clients/other systems providers] during pre-implementation requirements modeling sessions ... where simulating performance is necessary for really understanding requirements (e.g. CANbus network interactions); it is often ideal if we can work with a specification language or CASE tool like Rhapsody or Simulink RT Workshop that can be executable, modular and complete ... UML is not necessarily part of TDD, but it is part of an approach design synthesis that involves expending more effort understanding what is required first before writing any code *[and then wasting time trying to market that code to someone who cares*]; generally, more focus on understanding the systems requirements lays the groundwork for more efficient, productive agile TDD iterations.

Refactoring is about improving design -- cleaning up working, tested code to make it simpler, easier to maintain.  You want to tighten it up as much as possible to remove obfuscated tangles where for bugs might be hiding or could spawn in future releases -- you don't refactor because a customer requires it; you refactor because it's cheaper to ship clean code rather than to continue to pay the cost of supporting/maintaining complexicated mess.  Generally, most of TDD is more code-focused; but, you could employ UML for looking at larger scope or taking a step back to look at the problem, e.g. creating a Class diagram to help identify [missing] tests or possible refactorings.  This is not something you'd need to mandate or want to do on a general basis, but where appropriate.

The last step, 'ship' is a serious step ... 'ship' is not shorthand for "toss it over the wall and forget it, because good code doesn't need support" or "abandon and hope that there are no more iterations."   From a financial or business perspective, shipping is the most important step of TDD, because it is where you get paid.   Shipping does a involve "shifting gears" because it includes systems integration, preparation for support and maintenance, getting ready for the next round of development, etc.  The primary use of UML diagrams will be to communicate [in abstract terms] how the code does what it does ... UML is useful because hopefully the diagrams are an artifact of the requirements and development processes; it's not necessary to start from scratch when the code ships  ... as a communication tool, UML would be appropriate for reducing integration errors multi-module systems, larger projects that might involve modules written in different languages, networks of embedded systems where different companies must collaborate on safety-critical systems but need the abstraction to be stingy with or protective of their "proprietary knowledge."

Just as you should avoid using big hammer in situations where a tiny screw driver is appropriate OR you aren't going to get anywhere by asking all developers to standardize on using Emacs as their editor.  Sometimes the view is not worth the climb -- you don't want to always haul out the UML banner or become known a the guy who was alway pushing UML ... particularly not in situations where there is no substitute for writing tests or reading code.  If you stick to appropriate situations, you should not be afraid to use UML as a communication language in all situations where the language helps you.

Answer (score 9):

> Or is there any other way that would keep UML and TDD together?

UML and TDD fit wonderfully together:

1. Make the initial design in UML - it doesn't have to be complete, just consistent, self-contained
2. Create the empty tests. This step could also be automatized
3. All tests will fail at first, as required by TDD (because the generated code from UML does not have any code)
4. Start writing tests for each class

   1. Start with classes which do not have a great deal of associations if you are confident with your software architecture and UML skills (no, you're not doing waterfall, but sometimes you just know what you're doing - you know the application domain already or you have used expert knowledge at step 1)
   2. Start with classes which have a lot of associations ("central classes") if you are NOT confident in your understanding of the application domain - this will make it easier to eliminate as soon as possible bad design decisions, because you will notice them as early as possible
5. ... The tests are still failing
6. In parallel to each unit being tested (step 4), write the implementation inside the empty method bodies. DO NOT modify any class, interface or method names or parameter signatures. You ARE only allowed to add **private helper** methods, NOT more
7. If at step 6 (which is run in tandem with step 4) you realize you need to make changes in the design:

   1. Go to step 1 and refine the UML, then generate the code again (good UML tools will not overwrite your implementation). **Attention**: avoid introducing new classes. You want to finish step 13 within a few weeks
   2. Re-run the tests and fix the ones failing which were previously OK
   3. Continue with what you left at step 6
8. Go to step 6 if not all class tests pass
9. Proceed to component, package and subsystem tests
10. Add deployment to UML and deploy to the integration environment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_environment_%28software_development_process%29)
11. Proceed to integration tests
12. Go through the test/QA stage
13. Go through the User Acceptance Testing
14. Reiterate the previous steps as required (according to your iterative development process)
15. ... months pass
16. Deploy version 1.0.0 to production

Do not try to do arrive at many design decisions at step 1 or following reiterations of step 1 (refining the design). You want to finish step 13 in the first iteration after a few weeks.

Answer (score 8):

While some people think UML is a design methodology, it is first and foremost a communication tool. Hence the name, Unified Modeling Language. The idea is to have common vocabulary (of shapes) that you can insert in a book and everybody will understand.

TDD on the other hand is a design methodology, the way to construct the system starting from its interface and its consumer, and only then adding the implementation.

Once your design has emerged as a result of applying TDD, you can communicate that design using UML. If you don't need to communicate (like if you're the only developer), you arguably don't need UML.

Some people think of domain analysis (identifying key Nouns, Verbs and Adjectives and building a basic ontological model) as being a part of UML methodology, reflected in the use case & ER diagrams... This may be useful to do before you jump into TDD red/green/refactor cycle. Then again, strictly speaking this is DDD (Domain Driven Design), not UML per se.

Comment: It might be more expensive to write an interface, then some tests, finally start implementing code to see that you missed something fundamental, then you have to change your interface, and tests. I think you could benefit a lot from writing some UML and creating the interfaces from there.

Answer (score 6):

If you're designing classes using UML, you're designing what you *think* the code will look like. But what you *create* using TDD is the reality.

Leave UML until the end, to document the results of the code you created using TDD.

Comment: Unit testing first requires that you the developer know what the unit needs to do. It seems useful then maybe to solidify what you think the code should look like so that you at least have an idea what the responsibilities of each class might be. If they end up being something completely different in the end, that is also okay. As long as it is not thought of as set in stone, UML seems like a good way to get the ball rolling if you can't find a place to start.

Answer (score 2):

UML is the design part, of course.

I'd only use it on the system I was ending up with.  Rendering test classes in UML seems ludicrous to me.

I'd use it to get a general sense of what I was creating.  Then I'd start with TDD to implement it.

As far as keeping it in synch, I'd get a UML tool that was capable of import and export.  I'd worry more about the code and less about UML.  It's useful for capturing your thoughts and documenting later, but not much else.  I'd always prefer working, tested code over diagrams any day.